# How to use a Swin Transformer to generate an embedding, not classification?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, fast-ai

Using [timm](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models)'s implementation of Swin Transformer, how does one generate an embedding vector?

I would like to use `timm`'s `SwinTransformer` class to generate an embedding vector for use with metric learning (sub-center ArcFace).

What I've tried:

To create the `SwinTransformer` I have something like:

```py
from timm import create_model

backbone_name = 'swin_large_patch4_window7_224'
EMBEDDING_SIZE = 128 
NUM_CLASSES = EMBEDDING_SIZE # ???  
backbone = create_model(backbone_name, pretrained=True, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
```

This results in `backbone` having the structure:

```
SwinTransformer(
  (patch_embed): PatchEmbed(
    (proj): Conv2d(3, 192, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(4, 4))
    (norm): LayerNorm((192,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  )
  (pos_drop): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
  (layers): Sequential(
    ... *SNIP SNIP SNIP* ...
  )
  (norm): LayerNorm((1536,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool1d(output_size=1)
  (head): Linear(in_features=1536, out_features=128, bias=True)
)
```

So, I did what I normally do, which is freeze the backbone and replace the `timm`'s `head` with a 3-layer multilayer perceptron.

The "smoke test" of trying to train this was really poor, but I haven't started exploring training parameters, MLP layer sizes, etc.

Looking at the `SwinTransformer` architecture above, my intuition is that the weights going into `head` are already separating classes, not generating the activations for an embedding.

- Is there a layer in the `SwinTransformer` where I can grab the activations and put them into a simple MLP embedding projector?
- Should I just use the `SwinTransformer` as-is, no layers frozen, and train towards the output of `head` being an embedding? Won't that be very inefficient?

Comment: There is a close vote on this because it's "not about a specific program question." It absolutely _is_ a specific programming question. It's very frustrating to see how many valid machine learning questions are drive-by-closed on SO by moderators who don't seem to have much understanding of ML programming.

Comment: It might be a better fit for [datascience.se] or [stats.se].

Comment: Yes, I considered posting it on Data Science, but it seems to me essentially programming-related (it could almost be rephrased as "what's the index of the embedding layer?" The other stuff is just trying to answer "what is your goal? What have you tried?") and library specific (the correct answer relies on the use of the `timm` implementation).

Comment: In which case, rephrasing the question more like "how do I use this library" would probably help. Currently it feels like a question about the concepts involved. (Note: this is not my field.)

Comment: I tried to rephrase it per your suggestion.

Comment: I think you are ignoring that any layer of a neural network can be used as features or  embeddings, which makes both of your questions non-programming, since selecting which layers or deciding which layers to use is not a programming problem (it is research).